# Selector starting and ending at specific number

Tags: css, sass

Hi I am currently looking at a grid layout, where I need to be able to start a selector from a number defined in a data-attribute and end it on another number.
This is the markup I am working with:

```
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="1"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="2"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="3"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="4"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="5"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="6"></div>
<div class="plp__products__item" data-product-grid-position="7"></div>
```

I want to be able to select from `data-product-grid-position="3"` and until `data-product-grid-position="6"` for example. I am able to use SASS for the implementation.

```
.plp__products__item[data-product-grid-position=" from 3 until 6"] {
    background: green;
}
```

Im wondering if it is possible to write a function in SASS which would be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it'll work

```
@for $i from 3 through 6 {
    .plp__products__item:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the following SASS function does the trick:

```
@for $i from 3 through 6 {
    .plp__products__item[data-product-grid-position="#{$i}"] {
        background: green;
    }
}
```